# Java images collision

Tags: java, bitmap, collision

So, i'm trying to check collision between 2 images. The images have transparency, and the content may be as simple as a solid colores square, or as complex as a game character. Now, i need to find out wheter the image is colliding or not with other images. Per pixel collision is not a valid option, as image size can be really big, and that would be reeally unefficient, so whats my best option to detect if two images are overlapping (or simply colliding), without requiring a NASA computer? 
Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: How do you know if that would be very inefficient? And inefficient compared to what? Computers can't look at images the way you do.

Comment: Well, i think that comparing every single pixel with every other pixel of every image in the frame doesnt feel like the best way to do it... Maybe it is, i'm not sure, but that's why i'm asking!

Comment: You don't need every pixel, you need every pixel until you are sure they collide or not.

Comment: That means checking every pixel until you find a collision doesnt it? The fact is that most of the time they wont be colliding, so that would be checking every pixels most of the time, am I right?

Comment: No, it depends on how do you know that "most of the time they won't collide". You might only need to check the part where they could collide, ignoring the rest.

Comment: So, you are suggesting to check collision only in the border pixels of the image? How do you find out which pixels are borders, and which are inner ones?